Apache Arrow Flight Server as a Data As A Service
I am planning to build a arrow flight server on top of s3 data storage, the s3 data storage has petabyte of data.
I have few concerns when the flight server loads all the 1 pb of data in-memory it should lead to Out of memory
Secondly when we have incremental updates or new data arrives how we refresh the data ?
Thirdly we are planning to deploy into multiple nodes in a k8s cluster then every node will maintain a copy of data, I am concerned on such a huge data loaded inmemory and ideal way to sync data

If you're planning to allow download of the entire S3 dataset, you don't need Flight. All you need is the S3 API as it is. Flight is a protocol for data transfer like JSON over HTTP. Your service should be doing something interesting with the data source (e.g. filtering it) and returning small responses (max 2GB) to the client.
If you can manage to make a response based on the petabytes of data without putting petabytes of data in RAM (by any means), you can produce a Flight response.

Thirdly we are planning to deploy into multiple nodes in a k8s cluster then every node will maintain a copy of data, I am concerned on such a huge data loaded inmemory and ideal way to sync data

Why not have every node load data from S3 which is the system designed to store and serve petabytes of data with high concurrency?
